# Set web project root

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio 2015 asp.net project called Events.  There is a folder called app that contains all the project files I've added.  I have IIS pointing to the app folder and everything works fine.  However, for debugging in Visual Studio, I want to set localhost:12345 to the app folder.  For instance, the default page index.html is under the app folder.  When I type localhost:12345 I want to see index.html.  I don't want to see or type localhost:12345/app/index.html.  I see under properties that I can set the url for the project to the app folder, but I see "app" in the address bar.  I don't want to see it.  Is there a way to alias this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two years later and things are different nowadays.

Configuration of a web site resides only in

> \Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

When one changes *applicationhost.config* one may think that's the solution to  problem...

**BUT**

Visual Studio will detect that root folder is invalid, cos it's not pointing to the projects main folder. What then? VS will automatically change path that one thought is configured. Grrrrr...

**SOLUTION**

Edit project file in notepad and add one simple line in `<PropertyGroup>`:

`<WebRoot>public</WebRoot>`

Change public to subfolder in your project, VS will automatically change *applicationhost.config* to your new path. Be happy :)

Comment: Thank you!  I never did make this work.  Now using web.api so not so much of an issue.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working with VS 2019.  Adding <WebRoot> under <PropertyGroup> does not stop VS from re-writing the applicationhost.config file

Comment: Sorry but you get it wrong. You should never edit "applicationhost.config" file - this is automated file, controlled by VS. What you can edit is your PROJECT FILE. When you set a specific path in PROJECT FILE then VS will update applicationhost.config for you. Adding <WebRoot> will not stop VS from updating applicationhost.config. The goal is to tell VS what to update and give it a specified value. I still use it today in VS 2019 and it works. If you want to have a root website inside subfolder of your project place that subfolder name inside <WebRoot>YOUR_SUBFOLDER_NAME</WebRoot>.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't so obvious.  The goal was to have the visual studio IIS Express application match what regular IIS was doing. You have to change the IIS Config file and set the default document in web.config.  In vs2015, the folder is in the root of the solution folder: (make sure to unhide hidden folders).

.vs\config\applicationhost.config

Earlier versions are in the user folder:

\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

There is a section that maps the localhost:12345 to the physical path.

```
<site name="Events" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Development\AngularJs\Events\Events\app" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5064:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

I just added \app to the end of the physical path.  This can't be done in the project properties.  Also, the default document must be set in web.config.  If you set the start page in the properties, then you see index.html in the url. However if you add it in web.config, then the url is localhost:12345 and displays index.html, but doesn't show it in the url.

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="index.html" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Hope this helps!